# Как сделать так чтобы cin не ломался?

Tags: c++

собственно есть примерно такая конструкция

```
int k = 0;    
while(1)
    {
        if(k == 0)
        {
            cin >> k;
        }
        if(k == 1)
        {
            ///что то делаем
            k = 0;
        }
        if else(k == 19)
        {
            ///что то делаем
            k = 0;
        }
        else
        {   
            k = 0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Написал простенький пример, чтобы было легче показать:
Если ввести все кроме чисел то программа зациклится и cin сломается, подскажите как правильно выкрутиться из такой ситуации

Comment: У вас `=` вместо `==` if(k == 1) if else(k == 19)

Comment: ага опечатался но это не меняет сути проблемы

Comment: Если вы исправили `k = 19`, исправьте и `k = 1`.

Comment: О поверке ввода (результата `cin >>`) Вам уже сказали. Теперь предстоит решить, а что *надо делать*, если ввели *не число*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы должны проверять результат при чтении.

Например, так:

```
while (!(cin >> cmd))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "???" << endl;
}
```

Это для случая, когда ввод не может быть перенаправлен, иначе надо проверять `cin.eof()` (и может быть `cin.bad()`) по отдельности.

Comment: подробнее о том что написано в while

Comment: @MaximPro: условие в `while` проверяет, был ли ввод успешен. Если нет, то мы сбрасываем состояние ошибки (`clear`), игнорируем непрочитанную часть данных до конца строки (`ignore`), выдаём пользователю сообщение и вводим значение снова.

Comment: а нельзя вместо данной конструкции просто ввести cin, это же вроде тоже самое?

Comment: @MaximPro: Не вполне понял.

Comment: ну в условие после ввода данных(cin >> k) написать if(cin) далее код если ввод данных верный

Comment: Я не вполне понял ваш код поэтому прошу меня направить почитать тему по данному вопросу

Comment: Смотрите. Мы должны вводить до тех пор, пока не введём правильно. То есть вместо `cin >> cmd;` мы пишем целый внутренний цикл. В цикле мы крутимся до тех пор, пока не получим правильный результат. Выражение `cin >> cmd` возвращает назад тот же `cin`, так что проверка такая же, как в коде `cin >> cmd; if (!cin) { ...`, только в одну строку.

Comment: @MaximPro: Где почитать, не знаю :-(

Answer (score 0):

Либо читайте строку и сами преобразуйте ее в число с помощью `atoi`/`strtol`/`boost::lexical_cast`,
либо проверяйте что из `cin` было что-то считано с помощью `cin.gcount()`.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте в std::string (дабы исключить переполнение буфера), а ее уже парсите в нужный тип.

```
std::string raw_input;
int my_number = 0;

try_again:
std::cin >> raw_input;
try
{
    my_number = std::stoi(raw_input);
}
catch(std::invalid_argument ex)
{
    std::cout << "Упоролся?" << std::endl;
    goto try_again;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так:

```
int k=0;
while(1)
  {
  scanf("%*[^0-9]"), scanf("%d", &k);
  switch(k)
    {
    case 1:
      do_smth();
      break;
    case 19:
      do_smth_else();
      break;
    default:
      return 0;
    }
  }
```